# Why Navigation Menu Bar isn't sliding smoothly?

Tags: jquery, html, css

So, I've tried everything that I could with this. I'm using CSS and Jquery to make this effect. It's suppose to be simple: For responsiveness, when it gets to mobile phone width, it's suppose to have a transition to just a block menu. And when a user taps on it, it expands the menu (via Jquery) and it's suppose to open smoothly. But, it doesn't.

Here's my code:

HTML (JQuery at the bottom of HTML):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>The HTML5 Herald</title>
  <!-- <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css"> -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/home.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/responsive.css"
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<header>
  <h1>Best Website Since Google</h1>
</header>

<nav>
    <ul class="showing">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="handle">Menu</div>
</nav>

<section>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed iaculis sagittis vestibulum. Fusce laoreet tincidunt massa. In rutrum et libero a venenatis. Vestibulum malesuada sem sed pharetra pellentesque. In vitae tempus enim. Quisque porta, tortor ut bibendum lacinia, leo felis fringilla quam, ac euismod risus leo ut elit. Duis ornare velit vitae urna volutpat, condimentum sagittis nunc gravida. Vivamus placerat nibh ante, a mattis metus sodales quis. Curabitur luctus eros tortor, a venenatis nunc consectetur sodales. Ut ac orci ut libero porta tempus. </p>
  </section>



<script>
    $('.handle').on('click', function() {
      $('nav ul').toggleClass('showing');
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}

/************************************
************** HEADER ***************
************************************/ 

header {
    background: #00795f;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 40px 0;
    text-align: center;
}

/************************************
************* NAVRBAR ***************
************************************/

nav ul {
    background-color: #43a286;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-transition: max-height: 0.4s;
    -ms-transition: max-height: 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: max-height: 0.4s;
    -o-transition: max-height: 0.4s;
    transition: max-height: 0.4s;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
}

nav ul li:hover,
nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #399077;
}

nav ul li a,
nav ul li a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}

nav ul li a:active {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.handle {
    width: 100%;
    background: #005c48;
    text-align: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 15px 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
    display: none;
}

/************************************
************** SECTION **************
************************************/

section {
    line-height: 1.5em;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    padding: 40px;
    width: 75%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 580px) {
    nav ul {
        max-height: 0;
    }

    .showing {
        max-height: 20em;
    }

    nav ul li {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 15px;
        text-align: left;
    }

    .handle {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You needed to get rid of the extra colon. For example it was `transition: max-height: 0.4s;` and it should just be `transition: max-height 0.4s;`

```
-webkit-transition: max-height 0.4s;
-ms-transition: max-height 0.4s;
-moz-transition: max-height 0.4s;
-o-transition: max-height 0.4s;
transition: max-height 0.4s;
```

[Here's a JSBin](http://jsbin.com/verafixovi/edit?html,css,output) with the working code.